# FragmentStatePagerAdapter FragmentPagerAdapter always are static is better that way?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am learning to use viewpagers. and these classes, in the examples are always static is better that way, what is the difference if the charge first memory?